# Pythonic way to add Timestamps to pandas dataframe based on other Timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, vectorization

The funky way that you index into pandas dataframes to change values is difficult for me. I can never figure out if I'm changing the value of a dataframe element, or if I'm changing a copy of that value.

I'm also new to python's syntax for operating on arrays, and struggle to turn loops over indexes (like in C++) into vector operations in python.
My problem is that I wish to add a column of `pandas.Timestamp` values to a dataframe based on values in other columns. Lets say I start with a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mydata = np.transpose([ [11, 22, 33, 44, 66, 77],
         pd.to_datetime(['2015-02-26', '2015-02-27', '2015-02-25', np.NaN, '2015-01-24', '2015-03-24'], errors='coerce'),
         pd.to_datetime(['2015-02-24', np.NaN, '2015-03-24', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-27', '2015-02-25'], errors='coerce')
       ])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'BEFORE', 'AFTER'], data=mydata)

df.head(6)
```

which returns

```
    ID  BEFORE      AFTER
0   11  2015-02-26  2015-02-24
1   22  2015-02-27  NaT
2   33  2015-02-25  2015-03-24
3   44  NaT         2015-02-26
4   66  2015-01-24  2015-02-27
5   77  2015-03-24  2015-02-25
```

I want to find the lesser of the dates BEFORE and AFTER and then make a new column called RELEVANT_DATE with the results. I can then drop BEFORE and AFTER. There are a zillion ways to do this but, for me, almost all of them don't work. The best I can do is this

```
# fix up NaT's only in specific columns, real data has more columns
futureDate = pd.to_datetime('2099-01-01')
df.fillna({'BEFORE':futureDate, 'AFTER':futureDate}, inplace=True)

# super clunky solution
numRows = np.shape(df)[0]
relevantDate = []
for index in range(numRows):
    if df.loc[index, 'AFTER'] >= df.loc[index, 'BEFORE']:
        relevantDate.append(df.loc[index, 'BEFORE'])
    else:
        relevantDate.append(df.loc[index, 'AFTER'])

# add relevant date column to df
df['RELEVANT_DATE'] = relevantDate

# delete irrelevant dates
df.drop(labels=['BEFORE', 'AFTER'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df.head(6)
```

returning

```
    ID  RELEVANT_DATE
0   11  2015-02-24
1   22  2015-02-27
2   33  2015-02-25
3   44  2015-02-26
4   66  2015-01-24
5   77  2015-02-25
```

This approach is super slow.  With a few million rows it takes too long to be useful.

Can you provide a pythonic-style solution for this? Recall that I'm having trouble both with vectorizing these operations AND making sure they get set for real in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the minimum across a row (`axis=1`). Set the index so you can bring `'ID'` along for the ride.

```
df.set_index('ID').min(axis=1).rename('RELEVANT DATE').reset_index()

   ID RELEVANT DATE
0  11    2015-02-24
1  22    2015-02-27
2  33    2015-02-25
3  44    2015-02-26
4  66    2015-01-24
5  77    2015-02-25
```

---

Or assign the new column to your existing DataFrame:

```
df['RELEVANT DATE'] = df[['BEFORE', 'AFTER']].min(1)
```